# Como configurar el driver de una pagina abierta o activa usando selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript

Tenemos un proyecto donde debemos automatizar una prueba de una pagina con *Selenium WebDrive*, pero estando activa, es decir, no vamos abrir una ventana o navegador con el URL, este ya debe estar activo y hacerles las pruebas necesarias

Normalmente configuramos el *driver* y tomamos las propiedades de la página

```
driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));  // esto abre un nueva ventana y comienza la prueba
```

¿Como deberíamos configurar el *driver* de una una pagina abierta o activa usando *Selenium Webdriver*?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta
Si te refieres a usar webelement sin interfaz gráfica, lo que debes hacer es añadir

```
FirefoxOptions lOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
lOptions.setProfile(lFirefoxProfile);
lOptions.addArguments("--headless");
lOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
lOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
```

e iniciar el driver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(lOptions);
```

Saludos